# data collection with google analytics buggy since using next-intl

Tags: typescript, next.js, google-analytics, internationalization, next-intl

I have a project, which needs i18n using next-intl with app directroy and server components. This project also uses Google Analytics.

Now I have the following problem. My Cookie Banner automatically denies cookies despite me not setting it up this way. Please keep in mind, that Google Analytics did work prior to introducing next-intl. Since then, once the page is fully loaded, the consent banner automatically sets consent to false. I also tested it in a different browser. There I managed to set consent to true, but in my Google Analytics dashboard I did not see any data coming in while using the live feed.

I did some research and did not find anything. Maybe someone knwos what needs to be done here. Thank you in advance.

As i have some client components aswell I needed to use `NextIntlClientProvider`. I tried moving the files out of the localized routes and different ways for my `layout.tsx`. No matter what I did in this regard the outcome was the same.

Comment: Maybe your middleware accidentally rewrites requests that should go to Google Analytics? I'm currently adapting the docs in regard to the matcher, let me know if you have feedback: https://github.com/amannn/next-intl/pull/505

Comment: @amann For some reason it didn´t work in development but it worked as intended once I pushed to production. Thanks for your input! I will look into the docs.